# Getting 3 Hours Difference After Adding 27 Hours with Timedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

Imports as below:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

At first, I get date of the moment as seen:

```
foo = datetime.now()
```

And then I get 27 hours later as the following:

```
bar = foo + timedelta(hours=27)
```

Now I need to test this out. For this purpose, I use another variable as such:

```
baz = bar-foo
```

Now I test the difference between `bar` and `foo`:

```
seconds = baz.seconds
hours = seconds/60/60 # which returns 3.0
```

I have added 27 hours and got 3 hours difference between `bar` and `foo`.

What's the cause? Thanks in advance.

## Environment

- Python 3.6.5
- Manjaro 17.1.10 (if that really matters)

Comment: `str(baz)` -> `'1 day, 3:00:00'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking just the `seconds` attribute of a `timedelta` object is insufficient.

As per the [timedelta documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

> Only *days*, *seconds* and *microseconds* are stored internally.

Consider these components in turn:

```
days = baz.days
seconds = baz.seconds
microsecs = baz.microseconds

print(days, seconds, microsecs, sep=', ')
1, 10800, 0
```

You will need to add these together separately to get your total `timedelta`. If your aim is to extract the total number of seconds, you can use the `total_seconds` method:

```
totalsecs = baz.total_seconds()  # 97200.0
assert totalsecs / 60 / 60 == 27  # check we have 27 hours
```